# iOS push notifications works only in Debug mode on real device but not when downloaded from App Store

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a project that uses cloud functions to send out push notifications based on topic user selected .

user subscribe to topic :

```
 await FirebaseMessaging.instance.subscribeToTopic(('mytopic'));
```

Then my cloud function :

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
const fcm = admin.messaging();

      var payload = {
            "notification": {
                "title": msgData.name,
                "body": msgData.title,
                "click_action": 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK',
                "android_channel_id": "my_channel_id",
            },
    
             "data": {
               
                "content": msgData.content,
                "title": msgData.title,        
            }
        };
        return fcm.sendToTopic("/topics/" + 'mytopic', payload);
```

On Android it works 100% . Both in debug and on real device and when downloaded from Play Store .

On real iOS device it only works in debug mode . No notifications are received when I download from App Store

I noted this error at start up on my real iOS device but not sure what it means :

```
[FirebaseMessaging][I-FCM002022] APNS device token not set before retrieving FCM Token for Sender ID '123456789'. Notifications to this FCM Token will not be delivered over APNS.Be sure to re-retrieve the FCM token once the APNS device token is set.
```

Please also see Xcode screenshots :

[image]

I tried adding below into AppDelegate.swift as well as mentioned in similiar issue:

```
import UIKit
import Flutter


@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()//I ADDED THIS TO ATTEMPT FOR iOS push messaging to work in Release/Production Mode 
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}
```

I do ask for permission in code . To which i get prompted if I want to receive notifications from the app on real device :

```
  NotificationSettings settings =
        await FirebaseMessaging.instance.requestPermission(
      alert: true,
      badge: true,
      provisional: false,
      sound: true,
    );

    if (settings.authorizationStatus == AuthorizationStatus.authorized) {
      print('User granted permission');
      String? token = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken();
      print("The token is " + token!);
      // For handling the received notifications

    } else {
      print('User declined or has not accepted permission');
    }

    /// Update the iOS foreground notification presentation options to allow
    /// heads up notifications.
    await FirebaseMessaging.instance
        .setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
      alert: true,
      badge: true,
      sound: true,
    );
```

Some screenshots from Developer account :

[image]
[image]
[image]

I've been struggling to get this fixed . If anyone can assist . I would add more info if it would solve the issue . Thank you

Comment: Do you ask for permission to send notifications? Do you call `getToken`? Do you have APNS key from Apple Developer account added to `Firebase Console`?

Comment: Hi . I do ask for permission yes . I am not too entirely sure about the APNS key  . From what i can see from my developer account is that on the CERTIFICATES tab i have Apple Push Services . And from the Identifiers i have 'Communications Notifications ' and 'Push Notifications' selected

Comment: From the Keys tab , there are no keys

Comment: I have added screenshots from my Developer account pages

Comment: If you go to Firebase Console, under `Project settings`, on the `Cloud Messaging` tab, within `Apple app configuration` do you have any key or certificate set?

Comment: I have a key in Apple Developer account with `Apple Push Notifications service (APNs)` enabled. I download the key from here, take note of `Key ID` and in the console I upload it under `APNs Authentication Key`, making sure to enter `Key ID` as well.

Comment: I just registered for that Apple Push Notifications service (APNs) now . I downloaded the key

Comment: I just registered for that Apple Push Notifications service (APNs) now . I downloaded the key and uploaded it to my Firebase console ( iOs project ) . I'l test with a message from FCM console . THANK YOU

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252027/discussion-between-garth-and-peter-koltai).